# Jenkins Slave Is Shutdown Before "Idle delay" Timeout Not Working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have a Jenkins Slave configured to start and stop an Azure Ubuntu node.
*Launch method: Start and stop this node on demand.*
With a "Start script" and "Stop script" and using "Launch agent agents via SSH".

The VM is started and stop with custom scripts that run `az vm start` commands.  The scripts work.  And Jenkins gets connected and can make a build.

I have "Availability" set to "Take this agent online when in demand, and offline when idle".
*In demand delay: 1*
*Idle delay: 120*

However, after my build is done, the VM gets shutdown by Jenkins shortly after, in the range of a minute or two, not the 120 minutes specified.

Comment: Do Jenkins logs show that the agent is disconnected for some other reason before the stop script shuts down the VM ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up an on demand Jenkins linux slave using SSH, you might need to disable the sshd timeouts: https://www.simplified.guide/ssh/disable-timeout.

Otherwise it appears when the SSH connection is killed, Jenkins stops the VM.